# php student attendance status using radio button unable to store

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin, radio-button

I tried to store dynamically populated data database. There are 3 radio button value to be consider. Tried it for few time as such as change the type of the structure from int to enum but no luck. Hopefully that you all can point out and give an idea to fix it up. Thanks.

Sample of form:

```
<form action="try2.php" method="post" >
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'attendance')or 
die(mysqli_error());

$sql = "Select * from users where id=id";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}
echo '<table id ="tabGroup" align="center" style="cellpadding: 10px; 
cellspacing: 10px;">

<tr style="background-color:#ddd;">
<td scope="col" abbr="">&nbsp;</td>
<td scope="col" abbr="id" ><strong>Attendance</strong></td>
<td scope="col" abbr="stuName" ><strong>Name</strong></td>
</tr>
';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<td scope='row' class='spec'>" . '<input name="id[]" type="textbox" 
value="'.$row['id'].'" hidden>' . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . '<input type="radio" name="test['.$row['id'].']" 
value="1">attend<input type="radio" name="test['.$row['id'].']" 
value="2">Did not attend<input type="radio" name="test['.$row['id'].']" 
value="3">Drop subject' . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
  echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<table id="tabb" align="center">
<tr>
<td id="tabb" colspan="5" align="center">
<u><a href="student.php">Cancel</a></u>
&nbsp;<button class="mult_submit" title="Change" value="edit" 
name="submit_mult" type="submit">
<span class="nowrap"><img class="icon" width="16" height="16" alt="Change" 
title="Change" src="../images/b_edit.png">Change</span>
</button></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

process:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_mult']))
{
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'attendant')or 
die(mysqli_error());
$id=$_POST['id'];
$test=$_POST['test'];
for($i=1;$i<count($id);$i++)
{
    if($id[$i]!="" && $test[$i]!="")
{
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET test='$test[$i]' WHERE 
id='$id[$i]'");  
    }
}
}
?>
```

The problem is the database did not recognize it. Currently I set the test data type with enum with option of 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're not doing any error checking on the update query, so add that in.

Secondly:

`$i` likely won't match up correctly because in your form you're using `$row['id']` as the key.  I think you want the value of `$id[$i]` not `$i` when referencing the values in the `$test` array, or more simply since the id is the key in the test array:

```
foreach($test as $id => $test_value) {
    // You can assign the key into a variable with the foreach loop to simplify your for loops.
}
```

Comment: First answer: Added the mysqli_error and gain result `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Form\3\try2.php on line 34` line 34 started with if loop. The error presented when not all of rows the radio button are not selected.

Comment: Second answer: It work greatly. Thanks for the help. May I know why `$i` can't refer value of `$row['id']`?

Comment: `$i` is the incrementing count from your loop, so it is 0, 1, 2, etc.  `$row['id']` is going to be the column `id` from the current row while your looping through the query results.  They aren't referencing the same thing and likely won't ever hold the same value.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the help.